# WEB API Google Authentication access denied

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, google-authentication

I am trying to use google authentication API to have a google log-in on my web API project. Created the `OAuth`

[image]

and I enabled the Google+ API

[image]

added the `Client ID` and `Client Secret` on my `Startup.Auth`

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "497652290327-gd5h0lrheuqcrtccp2c4rqi8dt5vpfb8.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "sPGGSo2d7VZX7YnRNGmCPQDv"
        });
```

but when I try to log in the URI dispalys

```
http://localhost:54388/#error=access_denied
```

It consued me because I followed every steps from the tutorial of `kudvenkat` but still encountered this error. Did I do something wrong

Note that the credentials that I am using on this google log in does not exist on my database (if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have the lastest OWin / FacebookAuth Nuget packages and that your application has a valid connection string to a SQL database with migrations applied if using code-first.
Also check that the clientID & secret are correct, on the google apis console it should show some traffic on the client app

Comment: Updating to the latest nuget packages solved my issue with a clean VS2017 project.